# Can the split “query” and “aggregations” achieve higher performance？

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine I have an index "article" with 100 million pieces of data. Its template data  and mapping file are as follows. What I want to ask is, does splitting query and aggs (The following query1) and then using _bulk api to execute them has higher performance than executing a dsl alone(The following query2)? （elasticsearch version 7.x）

mappings：
`https://github.com/ZhangDi-d/elasticsearch-demo/blob/main/index_article_mappings.md`

template data:
`https://github.com/ZhangDi-d/elasticsearch-demo/blob/main/index_article_template_data.md`

**query1:**
include a "query" dsl and a "aggs" dsl

```
### query
GET /article/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "hidden": {
                  "value": "false"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "new_author_last_name": "Smith"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "view_cnt": {
                  "gte": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "simple_query_string": {
                      "query": "i",
                      "fields": ["content"]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match": {
                "author_first_name": "Danny"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match_all": {
              "boost": 1
            }
          },
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "follower_num",
            "factor": 1,
            "missing": 22.5,
            "modifier": "none"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": false,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "follower_num": {
        "order": "desc",
        "missing": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "view_cnt": {
        "order": "desc",
        "missing": 0
      }
    }
  ],

  "collapse": {
    "field": "userID"
  }
}








### agg
GET /article/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "hidden": {
                  "value": "false"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "new_author_last_name": "Smith"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "view_cnt": {
                  "gte": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "simple_query_string": {
                      "query": "i",
                      "fields": ["content"]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match": {
                "author_first_name": "Danny"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match_all": {
              "boost": 1
            }
          },
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "follower_num",
            "factor": 1,
            "missing": 22.5,
            "modifier": "none"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": false,
 
  "aggs": {
    "userID_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userID",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**query2：**

```
GET /article/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "hidden": {
                  "value": "false"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "new_author_last_name": "Smith"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "view_cnt": {
                  "gte": 1
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "simple_query_string": {
                      "query": "i",
                      "fields": ["content"]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "match": {
                "author_first_name": "Danny"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match_all": {
              "boost": 1
            }
          },
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "follower_num",
            "factor": 1,
            "missing": 22.5,
            "modifier": "none"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": false,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "follower_num": {
        "order": "desc",
        "missing": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "view_cnt": {
        "order": "desc",
        "missing": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "userID_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userID",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }, 
  
  "collapse": {
    "field": "userID"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async search, the async search API let you asynchronously execute a search request, monitor its progress, and retrieve partial results as they become available, for more information please check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/async-search.html).

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I think asynchronous is not what I want